# Magento Migration Foreign Key Error

Tags: magento

I am currently upgrading Magento and I can seem to get past this issue:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:211:"Error in file: "app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0.9-1.6.0.0.10.php" - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint";i:1;s:1132:"#0 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.6.0.0.9', '1.6.0.0.19')
#2 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.6.0.0.9', '1.6.0.0.19')
#3 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

**LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR**

```
2014-08-21 15:52:14 1ae404000 Error in foreign key constraint of table magento/catalog_product_entity_group_price:
FOREIGN KEY (`customer_group_id`) REFERENCES `customer_group` (`customer_group_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_GROUP_PRICE_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_GROUP_PRICE_WS_ID_CORE_WS_WS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) COMMENT='Catalog Product Group Price Attribute Backend Table' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci:
Cannot resolve table name close to:
(`customer_group_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_GROUP_PRICE_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_GROUP_PRICE_WS_ID_CORE_WS_WS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) COMMENT='Catalog Product Group Price Attribute Backend Table' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Switched table engine from MyISAM to InnoDB fix the problem.